# How to add labels to dropdown menu if the select options are coming from datatables javascript?

Tags: javascript, datatables, section508

I am using a datatable with dropdown filter for my project where I am popoluating the dropdown menu dynamically from the datatable. Automated 508 complaince tool is throwing the following error for the 3 dropdowns- "Elements with No Accessible Name: (3)". It also provides link to the following site on how to fix the error. https://www.ssa.gov/accessibility/andi/help/alerts.html?no_name_form_element.

I am not sure how to add labels since I am not defining the select options in the HTML. It is coming from Javascipt. Please see the code below.
Any guidance will be very helpful. Thanks.

https://live.datatables.net/finezici/1/edit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table-wrap').hide();
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    responsive: true,
mark: true,
stateSave: false,
    searching: true
  });

  buildSelect(table);
  $('#table-filter').on('change', function () {
    // show the tbody when the user clicks on a filter option
$('#table-wrap').show();
    table.columns.adjust();

    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });

 
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
    $('#table-wrap').hide();
  });
});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select><option value="">Select</option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');

    });

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
           // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox" select id="table-filter">
<p>Name: <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Postion: <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Office: <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
  <button type="button"  id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
  <div id="table-wrap">
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ID.AI</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett -2</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          
            
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can assign an ID to your select tag in JS by using your `counter` variable, then wrap the select labels in HTML with a `label` tag using the assigned ID hardcoded as the `for` attribute in `label`.

Comment: Thankyou, will you be able to provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is asking you to give labels for your dropdowns. To add the label `for` attribute you need IDs for dropdowns.
You can set it in your js as with `var select = $('<select id="dd' + counter + '"><option value="">Select</option></select>')`

Then you need to wrap your labels in a `<label>` tag using the dynamically generated ID in the `for` attribute.

Here is what it will look like: https://live.datatables.net/finezici/4/edit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table-wrap').hide();
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    responsive: true,
mark: true,
stateSave: false,
    searching: true
  });

  buildSelect(table);
  $('#table-filter').on('change', function () {
    // show the tbody when the user clicks on a filter option
$('#table-wrap').show();
    table.columns.adjust();

    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });

 
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
    $('#table-wrap').hide();
  });
});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select id="dd' + counter + '"><option value="">Select</option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');

    });

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
           // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox" select id="table-filter">
<p><label for="dd1">Name:</label> <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd2">Postion:</label> <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd3">Office:</label> <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
  <button type="button"  id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
  <div id="table-wrap">
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ID.AI</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett -2</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          
            
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```